# PHP - Re-format 2 dimensional array made from CSV to the pattern suitable for MYSQL import

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, multidimensional-array

I have a CSV file to be imported to MYSQL database.
The problem is that each line has different number of fields.
and their arrangement is rather random.
However, they can be divided into categories (text,images....etc).

In current form it's  too irregular for direct import to the database, so I tired to re-format it using PHP.

simplified example:

```
$messy = array( 
         [0]  => array("text1","text2" ),
         [1]  => array("img1.jpg" ),
         [2]  => array("text1","img1.jpg","img2.jpg"),
         [3]  => array("img1.jpg","text1","text2"),
            ...
         [1000]  => array("text2","img1.jpg","img2.jpg","text1")
         );
```

i would like the new array to match the following the pattern

```
array( 
         [0]  =>array(TEXT,TEXT,IMG,IMG),
         [1]  =>array(TEXT,TEXT,IMG,IMG),
```

in case of not sufficient data the remaining values=0;

```
         [0]  =>array("text1","text2",0,0),
         [1]  =>array(0,0,"img1.jpg",0),
```

i've tried to create new array and move "text" fileds to the begining like this:

```
$ordered=array();            
$i=0;

    foreach($messy as $row){

        foreach($row as $item){
            if (strlen(strstr($item,"text"))>0) {

                    if(($key = array_search($item, $row)) !== false){                   
                        unset($row[$key]);                      
                    }

                array_unshift($row,$item);

            }

        }


        $ordered[$i++]=$row;

    }
```

However it doesn't re-format, just reorder.

Comment: "img1.jpg" is actually text as well (a string), what is your criteria to decide if it is an actual image? what if the text is "I am adding img1.jpg"?

Comment: it's just simplified example i use explode to check the type - the original names are like da13c57cb019273f41ed16f365f7653f.jpg etc

Comment: That still does not help, as you need a clear way to distinguish TEXT from IMG. Following my previous examples, just looking at the extension does not work.

Comment: and i'm 100% sure the text field never contains string "jpg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function item_is_img($item) {
    $ext = pathinfo( $item, PATHINFO_EXTENSION )
    switch ( strtolower($ext) ) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'png':
            return true;
            break;               
        default:
            return false;
    }        
}

function reorder( $inputArray) {
    $resultArray = array();
    foreach ($inputArray as $line) {
        $t = 0;
        $i = 2;
        $result = array(0,0,0,0);
        foreach ($line as $item) {
            if ( item_is_img($item) )
                $result[$i++] = $item;
            else
                $result[$t++] = $item;
        }
        $resultArray[] = $result;
    }
    return $resultArray;
}
```

Completely untested. Assumes there are at most 2 TEXT types and 2 IMG types. Prone to failure.

Comment: Thank you very much!- Works perfectly after few modifications .